# How to check if a large Excel file is protected as quickly as possible?

Tags: python, openpyxl, win32com

How to check if excel file is protected with password the fastest way (without trying to open it and placing an exception)?

Updated:

```
from zipfile import *
from openpyxl import load_workbook
filename = 'Z:\\path_to_file\\qwerty.xlsm' # protected one
try:
    wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True, read_only=True) 
except (BadZipfile) as error:
    print(is_zipfile(filename))
```

A problem is that I got `False` as an output, thus I cannot get rid of the exception and replace it with `is_zipfile()` condition.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using and the exception, with the full traceback, you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using the openpyxl library:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(PATH_TO_FILE)

if wb.security.lockStructure == None:
    #  no password, act accordingly
    ...
else:
    #  password, act accordingly
    ...
```

Comment: i got an error: zipfile.BadZipFile: "File is not a zip file", the line i try to load_workbook (thought it was not a zip file at all, if i access the file normally the password is required), if i'm loading a protected file. Also even load_workbook(PATH_TO_FILE, data_only = True, read_only= True) takes significant time to open a heavy file, while my goal is to filter many files

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `protection._password` property of a sheet:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\...\\Downloads\\some_workbook.xlsx")

print(wb.worksheets[0].protection._password)
```

You can do this for whatever sheet you would like, based off the worksheets in the workbook.

If there is no password, the value is `None`. Otherwise, it returns the hashed password.

So, you can create a method to check this:

```
def password_protected(sheet):
   if sheet.protection._password is None:
      return False
   return True
```

The same method applies for the whole workbook, the property is just `workbook.protection._workbook_password`.

Comment: if i try to upload protected file, I got permission denied and  an error zipfile.BadZipFile: "File is not a zip file" (while it was not a zip file, but probably encrypted) , so this is a reason why i need to know weather the file is protected or not

Comment: Can you post some example code? And upload to where?

Comment: import openpyxl import load_workbook 
filename = 'qwerty.xlsm'
wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only = True, read_only = True) # fails here ! if depreciate  data_only, read_only nothing changes

Comment: are you providing the full path?

Comment: yes, and it works fine with all not-protected files from the same folder perfectly. I tried to open protected file as if it were a zip archive, but i got an error "not a zip file ". Actually I don't have a goal to open any passworded files at all, i need to filter 100500 files and keep not protected only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720587/python-reading-password-protected-word-documents-with-zipfile take a look at this

Comment: It seems that the easiest thing to do is catch the exception and move on. Especially if you don't care about files that are password protected.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to open a password protected workbook with openpyxl, this indeed gives a error zipfile.BadZipFile so a workaround would be to use:

```
import zipfile
zipfile.is_zipfile("workbook.xlsx")
```

Comment: Almost. A problem is that I got False  (code example is in the main question now)

Comment: Are all excel files workbook password protected? Because I guess it might evaluate to False when it is the worksheet that is password protected

Comment: No, some files are protected, and some aren't. The fact is that here result is false for all of them. So, this is_zipfile  is useless here.