# How to check if Excel file is password protected?

Tags: python, excel, passwords, password-protection

I am looking for help, how to check if my excel (`.xl*`) file is protected by password or not(I do not mean sheet_protection but whole file (work_book).

I was thinking about using vba by xlwings.api to do that, but can't figure out how to do that.
I found vba code for that here:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/12/17/determine-if-workbook-or-worksheet-is-password-protected-with-excel-vba?rq=password

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558302/how-to-check-if-a-large-excel-file-is-protected-as-fast-as-possible) as it seems already answered.

Comment: Unfortunately solutions from there are not working.
I want to avoid situation where exception inform me about password protection.

Answer (score 0):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Workbook.xlsx")

print(wb.protection.workbook_password)
```

it will return **None** if there is no password else something like a key but not the password

Comment: if you're looking to remove password from your excel file then this code might help you if all files have a same file then use it in loop else do it separately.

#def Remove_password_xlsx(filename, password):
   $ xcl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
   $ wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, False, None, password)
   $ xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
   $ wb.SaveAs(filename, None, '', '')
    $xcl.Quit()

Comment: I know how to open password protected excel, how to save it without password. I am looking for function/method to check if my excel is password protected. I want to avoid using try/except clause, because accidentally it may catch something else than password protected excel.