# How to detect if the xlsx file is password protected or not in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsx, password-protection

I have a required where I need to detect if the excel file is password protected or not. If password protected ask user for the password.
How do I do this in python?
I looked a bit on the internet, none of the answers were useful so far

Comment: Are you using openpyxl?  If so, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558302/how-to-check-if-a-large-excel-file-is-protected-as-quickly-as-possible

Comment: I have already gone through that thread. It gives `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` while loading the workbook. so none of the answer helped me @Pragmatic_Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines I guess.
If the file is encrypted it will pass and the password can be requested.
If it's not, it will error and the file can be loaded normally.

```
import openpyxl
import io
import msoffcrypto
from msoffcrypto.exceptions import FileFormatError  # pip install msoffcrypto-tool

filename = 'foo.xlsx'

with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    try:
        workbook = io.BytesIO()
        office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
        print("File is password protected")
        passwd = input("Please enter file password")
        office_file.load_key(password=passwd)
        office_file.decrypt(workbook)
    except FileFormatError as e:
        print(e)
        print("File is not password protected")
        workbook=filename

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(workbook)
    ws = wb['Sheet1']

    print(ws['A1'].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

after digging into the library I found the solution - https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool/blob/03d3298f7b8e27a26280bab1702bad36cce2e398/msoffcrypto/__main__.py#L23

```
import msoffcrypto
file_c = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(content) 
is_pwd_protected = file_c.is_encrypted()  #is_encrypted returns True if the file is password protected.
```